# Stopping a socket using a REST WebService - JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client

I am back again with another issue, I tried searching for an question/answer, but none of them   worked so far, so I decided to post another one.
I have a small REST JAXRS WebService in Java/Tomcat running, and from a JSP page I hope to send commands to start and stop a Socket Client. So far I achieved starting the socket, but I am not able to stop it, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1:**
I tested the same socket functions (using the same class PLC) with a JFrame interface with two buttons, one connect and other disconnect representing the REST functions, and it works

My Rest functions

```
NewTen_PLC m_plc = new NewTen_PLC(0x01, "Central Park", "10.80.4.10", 5001);
Thread m_thread;

@PUT
@Path("/connect")
public void Connect(InputStream is)
{       
    System.out.println("CONNECT COMMAND RECEIVED");
    try
    {
        System.out.println( "Starting Executor" );

        //Using thread manager
        //ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        //Start Thread
        //threadExecutor.execute(m_plc);            
        //Shutdown working threads when task is complete
        //threadExecutor.shutdown();

        //Using Thread
        m_thread = new Thread(m_plc);
        m_thread.start();

        System.out.println( "Tasks started, main ends.\n" );
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }       
}

@PUT
@Path("/disconnect")
public void Disconnect(InputStream is)
{
    System.out.println("DISCONNECT COMMAND RECEIVED");

    try
    {           
        //m_plc.closeConnection();          
                    m_plc.m_bConnected = false;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while trying to close socket");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

And this is the Class PLC that contains the Socket functions and the thread Run method.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Run (Thread)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        //DEBUG
        System.out.printf("\n Thread Started and Running in %s \n", getPLCName());
        //Connect to remote site
        connectToRemoteServer();
        //Set streams
        getStreams();
        //Process connection
        processConnection();
    }
    catch(EOFException eofException)
    {
        System.out.println( "\nClient terminated connection" );     
    }
    catch(IOException ioException)
    {
        ioException.printStackTrace();      
    }
    finally
    {
        closeConnection(); // close connection      
    }
}   
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Connect to Server/Remote Site
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void connectToRemoteServer() throws IOException
{
    //DEBUG
    System.out.println("Attempting connection to site");

    //Get IP Address
    InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(this.getIPAddress());
    //Create and Open Socket to server
    m_clientSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, this.getPort(), null, this.getLocalPort());
    //Set connected
    if(m_clientSocket != null)
        m_bConnected = true;
    //Set read timeout to infinite
    m_clientSocket.setSoTimeout(0);

    //DEBUG
    System.out.println("Connected to site");
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get in and out Streams
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void getStreams() throws IOException
{
    //DEBUG
    System.out.println("Setting Streams");

    //Input data stream
    m_inStream = new DataInputStream(m_clientSocket.getInputStream());
    //Output data stream
    m_outStream = new DataOutputStream(m_clientSocket.getOutputStream());
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Process connection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void processConnection() throws IOException
{
    NewTen_Buffer inBuffer = new NewTen_Buffer(8192);

    try // read message and display it
    {
        while(m_inStream.read() != -1 && m_bConnected == true)      
        {
            //Read 
            inBuffer.m_iSize = m_inStream.read(inBuffer.m_bBuffer);
            //DEBUG                  
            System.out.printf("Data read has %d bytes \n", inBuffer.m_iSize);

            //Decode
            newData(inBuffer);
        }   
            //DEBUG
        System.out.println("OUT OF READING LOOP");  
    } 
    finally
    {

    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Close Connection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void closeConnection()
{
    System.out.println( "\nClosing connection" );
    try
    {   
        System.out.println( "\nIn Try closing" );
        m_bConnected = false;
        m_clientSocket.close(); // close socket         
        //System.out.println( "\nClosing Data input streams" );
        //m_inStream.close(); // close output stream
        //m_outStream.close(); // close input stream
        //System.out.println( "\nShutdown ip op" );
        //m_clientSocket.shutdownInput();
        //m_clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
        //System.out.println( "\nClosing socket" );
        //m_clientSocket.close(); // close socket
        System.out.println( "\nEnd of Try closing" );
    }
    catch ( IOException ioException )
    {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    } // end catch      
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions how to stop it?

Cheers,
Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't fully read all the server code, but I'm guessing your server thread blocks waiting for a connection / input from stream, hence you can't stop it.

If you do have to use REST, you can force kill the thread to stop it (I can't guarantee the implication). Or other approach is implement a socket protocol to stop the server -- as opposed of using REST

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the quick reply, I tested the same functions with a JFrame interface and it works, so i can stop it (EDIT 1 above). I really want this to work with REST, but I will give it a shot with SOCKET. Cheers!

Comment: Force killing it doesn't help. It throws an exception, but it doesn't stop. I thought I was going to have problems making it connect, not disconnect :)

Comment: How did you force kill? Did you try to call `interrupt()` on `m_thread`?

Comment: Yep, I forced an Interrupt() on m_thread and got this exception SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [NewScada] in context with path [/NewWebScada] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.networkten.webscada.NewTen_PLC.closeConnection(NewTen_PLC.java:287)

Comment: Maybe the force kill actually worked -- it just that you haven't handled NPE properly. Try implement a catch-all on your thread code to handle it. Afterall if you choose not to stop gracefully you have to deal with it :)

Comment: Hey mate, tried, but didn't work. What I am finding difficult to understand is why I cannot change anything in m_plc after the thread starts. Like, if I do not start the thread I can change the properties, but after that nope. Any ideas?

Comment: That's because your `run()` method does `processConnection()` which does `while(m_inStream.read() != -1 && m_bConnected == true)`. The `read()` method will cause your thread to block waiting until a data is available. While at this state there's nothing else you can do except to interrupt it, or actually pass it some data so it can progress. I'd recommend you spending some time on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: That's what I thought, although what's really bugging me is that if I change the m_bConnected to false using a JFrame form the Thread gets out of the While loop and works. But if I do the same thing from the REST function it doesn't. I am reading through the link you gave right now to see if there is anything that I am missing